# jquery ajax .done function not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which I am useing to dynamically load html into a codeigniter view:

```
               $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "Ajax/getHtml",
                        data: { u : contents },
                        dataType: 'html',       
                        success: function(data) {
                            html = data;
                        },

                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                console.log('error');
                                console.log(jqXHR,textStatus, errorThrown);
                        },
                        done: function(){
                                console.log(' here is the html ', html);
                        }
                    });
```

I can see that the html is being returned correctly in firebug. However the 'done' function is not executing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You should you `.done` like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax/getHtml",
    data: {
        u: contents
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
}).done(function(html) {
   console.log(' here is the html ' + html);
});
```

Comment: Don't forget that this will only work if `html` is defined within the scope of both the `success` and `done` functions - ie. before the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan indeed - it would be better to omit the `success` handler altogether and just take `html` from the parameter passed to `.done`

Answer (score 2):

It's *usually* a design error to have both a `success` handler and a `.done` promise handler, and in particular the latter doesn't belong inside the `$.ajax` call - it gets chained from the *return value* of the AJAX call:

The modern pattern is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax/getHtml",
    data: {
        u: contents
    },
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function(html) {   // nb: data is passed here
   console.log('here is the html:' + html);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   //...
});
```